# How to determine the right Accept Content-Type with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, http-headers, http-accept-header

I'm having trouble to distinguish an ajax call from other calls in ExpressJS.

As far as I understand, I can use `request.accepts('json')` to identify a json request?

The problem is - apparently, every call accepts everything!

```
app.get( '*', function(request, response, next ) {
    console.log('request accepts:')

    if( request.accepts( 'json' ) ){
        console.log( '--> accepts json' )
    }
    if( request.accepts( 'html' ) ){
        console.log( '--> accepts html' )
    }
    if( request.accepts( 'blah' ) ){
        console.log( '--> accepts blah' ) // this does not show up
    }
    if( request.accepts( 'application/json' ) ){
        console.log( '--> accepts json2' )
    }

    next()
} )
```

If I just visit the page, it accepts json and html.

If I try to use `$.getJSON( ... url ... )`, it also acccepts json and html.

```
Headers:

Browser: "Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Ajax: "Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
```

I'm not an expert about the accepts headers, but it seems that the `*/*` part could be the issue.

How can I determine correct (or perhaps, the first) accept type in ExpressJS?
Alternatively: How can I distinguish a JSON request from a normal pagevisit?

Comment: Curious why you need to do this in the first place. If you need to serve different data types from same url most API's use a query param like `/path/to/server?format=json`

Comment: @charlietfl the main reason for this is because there is some path-independant middleware (that is called in every case) that I would like to disable during json based calls. Since the path routing seems to happen afterwards, I can't set a flag for it (since it's too late then). I can see 2 options: Either make a middleware that simulates the routing and checks if a specific path is called (meh!), or simply check the accepted types.

Comment: assuming that you have REST API that only serves json can't you just check if route contains main path for that api like `"/api/"`. Seems like a strange problem in general

Comment: Could also use `$.ajaxSetup` to set custom header based on `dataType` in `beforeSend` callback

Answer (score 0):

Almost all GET requests made by the browser are finished with `*/*`, it means that it accepts pretty much everything. In order to make a decision, you could check `req.accepted` array. It looks like this:

```
[ { value: 'application/json',
    quality: 1,
    type: 'application',
    subtype: 'json' },
{ value: 'text/html',
     quality: 0.5,
     type: 'text',
     subtype: 'html' } ]
```

Thereby, if JSON is present it is a special request, otherwise it is a simple request

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution that seems to work, by using an array for `accepts()`:

```
if( request.accepts( [ 'json', 'html' ] ) == 'json' ) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```